# connect Tableau online to my aws S3 bucket using Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have an aws S3 bucket which contains .csv files.

I would like to display them in a Tableau online dashboard by connecting my bucket to Tableau through Athena. I have followed this tutorial https://blog.openbridge.com/how-to-use-amazon-athena-views-within-tableau-in-3-simple-steps-c810396a2e3b and managed to connect Tableau to my bucket using the correct server, staging directory and AWS credentials. However I can't see the .csv contained in my bucket in the left "Table" panel. The only table I see is "elb_logs" in database "sampledb" which seems to be some sort of connection logs.

Is there something I missed like giving permission to Tableau in aws?